# Разные способы передачи массива в функцию, чем они отличаются?

Tags: c, массивы, функции, передача-параметров

Два способа передать массив в функцию:

```
void foo (int* arr) {
....
}
```

или

```
void foo (int arr[]) {
.....    
}
```

В чём разница?

Comment: В форме записи :)

Comment: Если функция работает с этим аргументом именно как с массивом, то лучше (для понимания другими читателями кода) писать `arr[]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Тут нет никакой разницы. И там и там передастся указатель на начало массива.